# vim regex :s/^\s*\(.\)\+/\\\1/g only shows last character substituted

Tags: vim, regex

I need to prepend a backslash \ to each character in a string, excluding any leading whitespace. I believed the following would do the trick.

```
:s/^\s*\(.\)\+/\\\1/g
```

but it produces this result for the string shown

```
   abcde
\e
```

i.e. it shows only the last such replacement, not each of them.

Vim provides 2 regex engines, which you can access explicitly by prepending the search string with either '\%#=1' or '\%#=2'. Both produce the same result.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Your regexp captures the complete input string `abcde` captures the 'e' and replaces that by `\e`.

You probably want something more like this: `:s/\S/\\&/g`